# How to use a share mutable struct field to read and write to in the same method

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, ownership

I'm trying to use a shared `Vec3` in my `Mat4` struct to do some calculations

```rust
struct Vec3 {
  x: f32;
  y: f32;
}

struct Mat4 {
  values: [f32;16];
  tmp_vec3: Vec3;
}
```

I have this method inside `Mat4`:

```
impl Mat4 {
  pub fn set_to_look_at(&mut self, position: &Vec3, target: &Vec3, up: &Vec3) -> &mut Self {
    let tmp_vec = &mut self.tmp_vec3;
    tmp_vec.set_from(target).sub(position);
    self.look_at(position, &tmp_vec, up)
  }

}
```

This code does not compile, complaining `cannot borrow '*self' as mutable more than once at a time`.

What is the pattern for this?

Comment: You would have to show us `set_from`, `sub` and `look_at` methods, to be sure, but I think the problem is with the line `self.look_at(position, &tmp_vec, up)`. `tmp_vec` mutably borrows `self`, and so (I believe) `look_at` does. Even if in the implementation you don't mutate `self.tmp_vec3` the compiler cannot see that. Maybe you could inline this function and it would work, but to be sure you have to provide full minimal reproducible example.

Comment: `Vec3` is small enough you should probably just make it `Copy` and pass values instead of references. On a 64-bit machine, `Vec3` will be the same size as a pointer, so copying it will do the same amount of work as passing a reference, but without the indirection. So there's no drawback and only benefits, including solving this issue.

Comment: @cdhowie my current implementation in fact initialize a new Vec3, but for something larger (like a temporary Mat4), I want to have that shared instance.

Comment: The compiler is right to forbid this code; without `Vec3` being `Copy`, `tmp_vec` points into `self.tmp_vec3` and thus could be modified by `self.look_at` despite being an immutable reference. Any sound implementation would have to somehow copy or clone `tmp_vec` before using it in `self.look_at`.

Comment: @BallpointBen is this achievable with RefCell<T>?

Comment: @hope_is_grim I want to say no — the fundamental issue here is that the borrows *are* overlapping. Using a RefCell would just delay this issue until runtime, but it would still be a problem.

Comment: @BallpointBen got it now, instead of overlapping borrows, I just need a new method that doesn't accept any Vec3 at all, since that vec3 is accessible from `self` already. And a Vec3 is not a very good example, a [f32;32] should be a better one. Not copying that saved my batch ~10 FPS for the method will be called every frame.